Finding derivative over multiple independent variables.
I'm trying to find the derivative dP/dQ given the following equations:
Q = Q1 + Q2
P = 120 + 5(Q1 + 2Q2)2
I understand that I need to use the chain rule, but I'm a bit confused about how to handle the fact that Q1 and Q2 are both implicitly functions of Q. Can someone provide a step-by-step solution or point me in the right direction?
